# C# Vector to Quaternion Rotation Issue

Tags: c#, vector, quaternions

I've got a fairly intricate issue. Essentially, I've got an object that tracks a players position, using a LOS algorithm to always fly towards the players current position.

I'm having an issue however, as I'm trying to get the object to shoot bullets in the direction of the player. The object uses pure vector mathematics to move towards the player, but considering how my functions operate, the bullets need to use quaternions.

So, if an object moves towards a player, how can I make a Quaternion rotation that can be used by the bullet function to create bullets that also move towards the player with their source being the object?

**My function to draw the object that follows the player:**

```
private void drawEnemy(GameTime gameTime)
{
    angle += 0.1f;

    velocity = Vector3.Normalize(xwingPosition - enemyPos) * 0.02f;

    enemyPos = enemyPos + velocity;
    enemyWorldMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(enemyPos);
    DrawObject(enemy, enemyWorldMatrix, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix);

    //enemyRotation = GetRotation(xwingPosition, enemyPos);

    //Quaternion additionalRot = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(0, -1, 0), -0.1f) * Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), -0.1f);
    //enemyRotation *= additionalRot;

    double currentTime = gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    if (currentTime - enemyLastBulletTime > 1000)
    {
        EnemyBullet newBullet = new EnemyBullet();
        newBullet.position = new Vector3(enemyPos.X + 0.2f, 71, enemyPos.Z + 0.2f);
        newBullet.t = 0.01f;
        newBullet.proportion = newBullet.t / 120;
        newBullet.playerPosition = xwingPosition;
        newBullet.enemyPosition = enemyPos;
        newBullet.currentAccel = 0.025f;
        enemyBulletList.Add(newBullet);

        enemyLastBulletTime = currentTime;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it uses vector maths to track and move towards the player.

As you can see, I'm trying to create bullets. The bullets use a Quaternion rotation that I'm hoping I created correctly.

My **function to update the positions of the bullets** once they are created from the first function I wrote.

```
private void UpdateEnemyBulletPositions()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < enemyBulletList.Count; i++)
    {
        EnemyBullet currentBullet = enemyBulletList[i];
        currentBullet.t += 0.01f;
        currentBullet.position = enemyPos + (Vector3.Normalize(currentBullet.playerPosition - currentBullet.enemyPosition) * currentBullet.proportion);
        MoveForward(ref currentBullet.position, currentBullet.rotation, 0.04f + (currentBullet.currentAccel));
        enemyBulletList[i] = currentBullet;

        BoundingSphere bulletSphere = new BoundingSphere(currentBullet.position, 0.05f);
        CollisionType colType = CheckCollision(bulletSphere);
        if (colType != CollisionType.None)
        {
            enemyBulletList.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;

            if (colType == CollisionType.Target)
                gameSpeed *= 1.05f;
        }
    }
}
```

*xwingPosition* is the players current position.

*enemyPos* is the current position of the object that follows the player

**The issue is shown in this youtube clip which Im just preparing...**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnkCVKdfN9Y

I think the problem lies with setting t to the total elapsed milliseconds rather than a counter starting from 0. Thing is, I don't know how to start a counter from 0 each time a bullet is made.

Comment: I am not sure you need to rotate anything to calculate the trajectory of the bullets. Of course, if your bullets are not spherical in shape, you would need the rotation to draw their shape. Is this your problem?

Comment: the bullets are basically just a vector3 pos for the sake of this.
don't I need rotation to indicate which direction to travel in?

Comment: Say the player is in position P and the enemy in position E (P and E both 3D vectors) then the trajectory will be a function: T = E + t(P-E) with t ranging from 0 to 1

Comment: So technically, I'd be better off not being stubbron and modding my UpdateEnemyBulletPositions() function so that instead of using rotation for direction is uses simply the function you mentioned?

Comment: Let's say I did want to use a quarternion anyway. How would I convert the needed trajectory to a quarternion so that my function can process it?

Comment: Well, to calculate this linear trajectory, you don't need a rotation. Not having to deal with angular math will also speed up your code.

Comment: Okay, so I tried changing it do that currentBullet.Position is  = Vector3.Normalize(xwingPosition - enemyPos) * 0.03f;

However, the bullets spawn where they should and then disappear.

Comment: (xwingPosition - enemyPos) is the vector that gives you the direction of your bullet. You have to multiply it by a factor ranging from 0 to 1 to animate your bullet, and add it to your enemyPos to make the movement start from the enemy (otherwise it would start from the origin of your system of coordinates)

Comment: Hmm. currentBullet.position = xwingPosition + (Vector3.Normalize(xwingPosition - enemyPos) * 0.03f);

That seems to make the bullets magically teleport straight to the player position without a velocity between the enemy and the player.

Comment: do not multiply it by a constant 0,03f but make it range from 0 to 1, to animate

Comment: Alright, I changed 0.03f to the angle variable from drawEnemy() function. However, the bullets all clump together into the same position and move all as one. How should I seperate them out?

Comment: 0.03f is not an angle variable. It is the proportion of the trajectory the bullet has moved in the path from the enemy to the player. You can have more than one bullet object. Higher t coefficients would show bullets closer to the player: if t=0 the bullet is starting its path. If t=0.5 then it is half way. If t=1 then it has hit the player

Comment: How do I calculate t? Your above function mentioned both t and T.

Comment: T is the resulting position of the bullet. t is a coefficient you have to animate from 0 to 1 to animate your bullet. If you start with t = 0 and add 1/60 to it (at 60 fps) your bullet would reach the player in one second.

Comment: That seems to work fine. The only issue now, is the line of bullets going from the enemy to the player moves as the players move, so the bullets always follow the player anyway. I need it so once they initially spawn and head towards the player at that exact time, they keep heading to where the player WAS, not where the player is NOW. Would a static variable or something be required for this?

Comment: That's easy to solve. In your bullet object keep two vectors: one for the enemy's initial position, and one for the player's initial position. Copy them when the bullet is fired and then base your computations on those and not their new positions.

Comment: But where would I assign the current positions of players and enemys to Bullet struct variables. That method gets called every second, wouldnt new positions keep getting written into it?

Comment: Each bullet would need to have its own t variable, to keep track where it is in the trajectory. Just copy the vectors if(t==0) since that is the exact moment when the bullet gets fired.

Comment: I'm still having an issue that's difficult to explain, so I'm going to  upload a video of it. Essentially, the bullets do retain their direction once created and don't keep gravitating towards the player, which is good. However, they keep creating one after the other in front of each other, until there is a line of bullets going from the enemy object to the player object, and even past the player object. These bullets still move towards the player position, but are created in a long line.

Comment: Am I right in that this is XNA?

Comment: XNA is a games oriented library for C#. And yes, this is XNA

Comment: Well, you have to stop creating bullets. Also, when t==1 then you can make your bullet explode and disappear

Comment: But as in, the first bullet spawns at t == 0, the next one spawns at t == 0.1, and so on.

Comment: I gotta go for lunch; back in a couple of hours ;-)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnkCVKdfN9Y

Comment: I think the problem lies with setting t to the total elapsed milliseconds rather than a counter starting from 0. Thing is, I don't know how to start a counter from 0 each time a bullet is made.

Comment: I expanded my answer. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linear trajectory between two points E and P (3d vectors representing the enemy and the player) can be calculated with the following formula:

```
T(t) = E + t*(P-E)
```

where t is a coefficient that varies from 0 to 1 (for the bullet to animate).

This is a base you can build from. However, you might want your bullets to have a limited reach. If that was the case, you could do the following:

1. Calculate the direction of your bullet: `D = P-E`
2. Calculate its length: `len = sqrt(Dx^2 + Dy^2 + Dz^2)`. Where Dx is the x coordinate of D, etc., and ^2 means squared
3. Normalize the direction vector `ND = (1/len)*D`. (Just divide each coordinate by `len`)

Now, in `ND`, you will have a vector of length one, in the direction of the enemy to the player. Every time you fire a bullet, you should allocate a structure where you store:

- The current `ND`
- The position from where the bullet gets fired (which is `E`, the current position of the enemy)
- A counter t = 0

In every cycle of your game, for each bullet that is "alive" (the following is pseudocode):

```
bullet.t += 1
if(bullet.t < maxNumberOfCyclesABulletLives){
  bPos = bullet.E + bullet.t * coefficient * bullet.ND // coefficient is the distance the bullet should move in each cycle
  if(bPos touches P){
    damageToPlayer()
    releaseTheStructureForThisBullet()
  }
  else drawBulletInPosition(bPos) // depending on your gaming library, you may have to erase it from the previous position
}
else{
  makeTheBulletExplode()
  releaseTheStructureForThisBullet() //or rather return it to a pool, where it can be reused
}
```

By the way, you game looks quite cool. I expect a free copy once you publish it ;-)

Comment: So given the bug I have in that video, where do you think my code is going wrong? Also I don't know anything about counters...

Comment: I think you are probably not erasing your bullet when you move it to a new location. Or you may be generating bullets and not destroying them . By counter, I mean just an integer variable that you increment by 1 in every cycle of your game.

Comment: The issue seems to be though that each bullet is spawning infront of where the previous one spawned. I've toiled through the code and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Maybe the enemy spaceship is moving towards the player in the direction of the bullet? Maybe you are not starting your new bullet setting its t=0?

Comment: If t is a variable that is derived from the gametime, how can I always have it start from 0?

Comment: It is not derived from the game time. It starts to count whenever a bullet is fired. Each bullet should have its own instance. Maybe the name `t` is confusing; just call it something else.

Comment: Well, I created newBullet.t = 0.01f; and newBullet.proportion = newBullet.t / 120; Which is created as a variable for each bullet that is made. Then, t is incremented gradually when the bullet position updates. My bug still isn't solved. I updated my original psot with my current code, just incase you can notice any obvious mistakes.

Comment: I think what is missing is the part where you take your bullet off the list. I would check newbullet.t against a max value and, when it reaches it without making impact on the player, just destroy the bullet and remove it from the list. Otherwise, you will create an endless stream of bullets that will travel into infinite space.

Comment: I don't mind if the bullets travel into endless space, it's the very fact they're getting created in front of the last bullet, and not at the location of the last bullet that bothers me.

Comment: It is also a resources issue: if you don't get rid of useless bullets, your list will eventually become very large and, to process it, it will take time that will slow down your game. At some point, you will also run out of memory and your game will crash. There is an error in UpdateEnemyBulletPositions(). The third line inside your `for` statement should be `currentBullet.position = currentBullet.enemyPos + ...` Otherwise you would use the position of the enemy now, not the position it was when the bullet was fired.